# With Angular 11 Icons getting corrupted when compiled into styles.css

Tags: angular-cli

After running ng build and running the app from dist folder, the Icons are getting corrupted and they're displayed weird symbols. I am using one of the custom icon font library created by icomoon. Is there any additional configuration that needs to be done?

Here is the package.json dependencies:
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~11.2.11",
"@angular/cdk": "^11.2.11",
"@angular/common": "~11.2.11",
"@angular/compiler": "~11.2.11",
"@angular/core": "~11.2.11",
}
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.10",
"@angular/cli": "~11.2.10",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.11",
}